# Youtube iframe video restarts after modal box is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, colorbox

I am using colorbox to pop up a video when a webpage loads. I am using the inline html option with the colorbox modal and I have an iframe youtube video in the modal box. When I close out of the video the audio stops but then it loads again and starts playing. When I close the modal box I would like for the audio to not start playing again.

Here is my script that opens the modal when the page is loaded:

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery.colorbox({width:"602px", height:"460px", inline:true, href:"#video_popup"})
      });
</script>
```

Here is the actual inline content:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="video_popup">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6A8W77m-ZTw?&amp;autoplay=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The video will only restart if an update occur — are you bringing the video with AJAX, maybe?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any update going on and no AJAX. The whole set up includes the colorbox js file and the colorbox css file, as well as the js/html in my post and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display iframe content (embedded youtube), remove the html code and try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery.colorbox({innerWidth:602, innerHeight:460, iframe:true, href:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/6A8W77m-ZTw?&amp;autoplay=1&controls=0"})
  });
```

If you want to display iframe content in inline format (for some reason):

The inline element would be appended to original parent element after user close the modal box.
So iframe will be loaded again and the video will play even though it's invisible. (because you set the youtube embedded url para autoplay=1). To solve this problem I register a handler for cleanUp event which will be fired at the start of the close process. I change the iframe src url param "autoplay" to 0 before modal window start to close. The audio will not play after modal window closed.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery.colorbox({
        width:"602px", 
        height:"460px", 
        inline:true, 
        href:"#video_popup", 
        onCleanup: function(){
            $("iframe").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/6A8W77m-ZTw?&amp;autoplay=0&controls=0");
        }

});
```

Comment: Well, that kind of works. I mean it solves the problem of the audio restarting after the video is closed but I need to use the html/inline content because I need to have a button in the modal box under the video.

Comment: I updated the answer and I think it could solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah that looks great! I am getting an Unexpected end of input error though. Any ideas?